# Normality test in panel data analysis

Tags: panel-data, normality-assumption, central-limit-theorem

Is it necessary to perform normality test such as Jarque Bera, Kolmogrove etc in panel data analysis? Assume I have 3000 obervation..Since the observation size is big, can I just assume that the data is normal as the assumption in the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: The central limit theorem doesn't say *anything* about many observations making the *data* come from a normal distribution (and certainly not as an assumption). As for whether a formal hypothesis test is necessary, I'd actually say it's usually *counterproductive* because (i) it often leads you to take exactly the wrong action (you're more likely to reject when it matters least, less likely when it matter more, since power is related to $n$) and (ii) changing your choice of inferential procedure on the basis of tests of assumptions adversely impacts the properties of the resulting inferences.

Comment: so, is that mean I could just ignore the normality test? In my research area which is capital structure, I found lack of references to guide me on the normality issue. Most of the references are silent. So I am a bit unclear on this issue..Perhaps, you can advise me further.TQ

Comment: My objection was to hypothesis tests. You shouldn't necessarily pretend normality is not relevant; how important a given amount of non-normality will be depends on what you're doing and on sample size (among other things).

Comment: Noted on the above.TQ..Like in my case, I performed fixed effect model and my robust result indicates all variables are significant..I suddenly come across with the normality test that should be done earlier before further data analysis..My concern is, should I go back and perform normality test first before proceed further analysis? And if non normality exist, should I transform my data? TQ

Comment: "suddenly come across" ... where was this, and what, exactly does it say?

Comment: I mean, I found 1 paper doing normality test in my research area. But as I mentioned earlier, most paper in my research area is silent on the issue of normality test...so I want to reconfirm my data analysis procedure as I worried if I missed important test (which is normality test). TQ

Comment: Can you give a reference to the paper in your question please, and if possible quote the part that provoked your question?